# How to trigger the animation to only start when content is on screen

Tags: html, css, animation, triggers, progress-bar

hope you're doing great.
First, apologies for posting a question that has been asked before by other users.
I tried searching for already posted solutions but none of them worked for me.
Most likely it didn't worked because i'm a newbie and i did not know how to implement the solutions in my code properly.
Currently my animations start once the page is loaded and are not visible, as they are lower in the body of page. By the time the user scrolls down to the part where the animations are, the animations have already played and finished.
Can i please get some help with triggering my animations only when they are in view on the page ?
Many thanks.

```css
.flex-container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container1>div {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.progress-bar-ai {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #310000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-ai {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  background: #EEA808;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 90%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  float: right;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}

.progress-bar-dw {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 30px;
  background-color: #480036;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-dw {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  background: #FF40F0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 40%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
  width: 0;
  animation-name: trigger;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container1">
  <div class="progress-bar-ai">
    <div data-size="20" class="progress-ai"></div>
  </div>
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/Illustrator.png" width="90" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/Dreamweaver.png" width="90" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
  <div class="progress-bar-dw">
    <div data-size="20" class="progress-dw"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that is possible with pure css but, I did something like that with javascript using the 'intersection observer api'.
(see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API )

You can use that to 'observe' when an element gets into view and when it does add an extra class. Something like this:
(When the items scroll into view, I add the class 'play-animation'. That class has the animations and transitions that need to happen. The code might not be perfect, but should give you a starting point)

```js
/* Tell the 'observer' what needs to happen */
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  //loop through all the elements given to the observer
  entries.forEach(function(element) {
    //isIntersecting is true when the element is being scrolled into view
    if(element.isIntersecting === true){
            //do something      
      element.target.classList.add("play-animation");
       
      /* 
       * optional: By callsing the 'unobserve' the element gets removed from the observer 
       * (by doing this, if the element is scrolled out of view and back into view after, nothing will happenn) 
       */
      observer.unobserve(element.target);
    }
  });
}, { threshold: [0] });

/* now tell the observer what elements to loo for */
observer.observe(document.querySelector('.progress-ai'));
observer.observe(document.querySelector('.progress-dw'));
```

```css
.flex-container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container1>div {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.progress-bar-ai {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #310000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-ai {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  float: right;
}

.progress-bar-dw {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 30px;
  background-color: #480036;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.progress-dw {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 14px;
}
.progress-dw.play-animation {
  background: #FF40F0;
  width: 40%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}
.progress-ai.play-animation {
  background: #EEA808;
  width: 90%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
  animation: load 2s normal;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
  width: 0;
  animation-name: trigger;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>&nbsp;<br />Scroll down<br />&nbsp;</div>
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x1500.png" width="300" height="1500" alt="..." />

<div class="flex-container1">
  <div class="progress-bar-ai">
    <div data-size="20" class="progress-ai"></div>
  </div>
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/Illustrator.png" width="90" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/icons/Dreamweaver.png" width="90" height="auto" alt="..." /></div>
  <div class="progress-bar-dw">
    <div data-size="20" class="progress-dw"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, i appreciate it.
I can see the code you wrote is working on this page when i run the snippet.
However, i struggled all day to get it working but when i put this in my index.html is not working, animations still starting as soon as the page loads.
I am not sure if there is anything else in my code that might interfere with what i'm trying to accomplish.
Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: @Bud.420 Did you copy the changes to the css I made? I made some small changes to the classes progress-dw and progress-ai and added .progress-dw.play-animation and  .progress-ai.play-animation.

Comment: Yes i also added the progress...play-animations in css without any luck

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply (I had a busy over the weekend), but the only other thing I can think about right now (if you don't have it working yet): did you place the javascript at the bottom of the page? If not, try placing the script-tags at the bottom of the page before the `</body>`-tag. This way the script runs after the html code it needs to keep an eye on.

Comment: Apologies for the very late reply. been crazy busy with work lately.
After playing a bit with the code i managed to get it working.
Thank you for your help Nathan :D